# Add a "Fux" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

I did a quick search for "fux is:question" and got 39 results. We get Fux-related questions often enough that I wonder if we should either:

1. Add a [fux](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fux) tag, or
2. Add [fux](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fux) as a synonym for [species-counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-counterpoint).

Most of the results in my search were tagged with [counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counterpoint) or, less often, [species-counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-counterpoint), and the ones that weren't appeared (at a glance) to mention Fux but not be questions about Fux.

The [counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counterpoint) tag currently has 194 questions, and the [species-counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-counterpoint) tag has 19.

**Proposal:** Add [fux](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fux) as a synonym for [species-counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-counterpoint), and make sure [species-counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-counterpoint) is applied to appropriate questions.

Answer (score 3):

[fux](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fux) has been nominated as a synonym for [species-counterpoint](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-counterpoint). Four up-votes, or moderator magic, are required for approval.

Votes can be placed at https://music.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested.